# Using Array html element naming convention with Zend Form inside View Script Decorator /

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, view-helpers

```
 $mon = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('days[mon]');
 $tue = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('tue');
```

how will I access "days[mon]" element inside view script for the form

```
$form = new Zend_Form();
$form->addElement($mon);

$form->setDecorator('form',array('ViewScript','viewscript'=>'form.phtml'));
```

I can easily access "tue" inside form.phtml

```
   $this->element->tue
```

but how to access "days[mon]" ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, for this puposes you should use subforms.

For example:

```
        $mainForm = new Zend_Form();
        $daySubForm = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
        $mon = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('mon');

        $daySubForm->addElement($mon);
        $mainForm->addSubForm($daySubForm, 'days');

        var_dump($mainForm->days->mon);
```